# What is wrong with my javascript selector for my function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I have a webpage with a `div` and a few images in it. The `div` has the id of "slideshow". I am trying to make a slideshow function, but with a more "customised" way of selecting the `div`. However, this doesn't work, what is the problem? I put the "old" code right under the newer one, there are 2 lines that need to be modified to see the wanted result. the link: https://en.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/js-library-exatreojs-slideshow-library/2950604004

```
var slideShow = function(container, time) {
    this.images = [];
    this.curImage = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < container.childElementCount; i++) {
        this.images.push(container.children[i]);
        this.images[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Handle going to to the next slide
    var nextSlide = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
            this.images[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        this.images[this.curImage].style.display = "block";
        this.curImage++;
        if (this.curImage >= this.images.length) {
            this.curImage = 0;
        }
        window.setTimeout(nextSlide.bind(document.getElementById(this), time);
        // old code (works): window.setTimeout(nextSlide.bind(this, time);
    };

    nextSlide.call(this);
};
slideShow("slideshow", 1000);
// old code (works): slideShow(document.getElementById("slideshow"), 1000);
```

Comment: The function is just seeing "slideshow" as a string, not as an element.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you're only passing in a string ("slideshow") and at no point are pulling any element with that as its `id` attribute.

You can extend your `slideShow` function to check to see whether the `container` parameter is a string, and if so, grab the relevant element:

```
var slideShow = function(container, time) {
    if (typeof container === "string")
        container = document.getElementById(container);

    ...
};
```

You should probably then also check if your `container` variable holds a `HTMLElement` before continuing execution:

```
if (!(container instanceof HTMLElement))
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var slideShow = function(container, time) {
        var containerEl = document.getElementById(container);
        this.images = [];
        this.curImage = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < containerEl.childElementCount; i++) {
            this.images.push(containerEl.children[i]);
            this.images[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        // Handle going to to the next slide
        var nextSlide = function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
                this.images[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            this.images[this.curImage].style.display = "block";
            this.curImage++;
            if (this.curImage >= this.images.length) {
                this.curImage = 0;
            }
            window.setTimeout(nextSlide.bind(document.getElementById(this), time);
            // old code (works): window.setTimeout(nextSlide.bind(this, time);
        };

        nextSlide.call(this);
    };
    slideShow("slideshow", 1000);
```